# ./configure: error: the HTTP gzip module requires the zlib library

Tags: meteor, docker, zlib

I am new to dockers/containers.

I am trying to run a fork with a fix I have put in for openSSL vulnerability of [mup-frontend](https://github.com/meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server) using the following command:

```
docker build ./
```

It compiles to a point then errors with

```
./configure: error: the HTTP gzip module requires the zlib library.
You can either disable the module by using --without-http_gzip_module
option, or install the zlib library into the system, or build the zlib library
statically from the source with nginx by using --with-zlib=<path> option.
```

I am running a mac so installed zlib with brew. I have searched long and hard but cannot find much on this error.

Because of this error it also fails to build on automation in docker.io

Comment: You need to install zlib in your container, so your Dockerfile will have an install of zlib

Comment: How do I do this locally? I'm used to working with npm modules - not so much with apt-get etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile you reference at

https://github.com/meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server/blob/master/Dockerfile

starts with

`FROM debian`

so you will need to have such a line in your Dockerfile, before the place where you need zlib

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zlib \
    --no-install-recommends \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

in one RUN, you update, install and clean

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install -y httpd-devel pcre perl pcre-devel zlib zlib-devel GeoIP GeoIP-devel


Download required packages

cd 
wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.10.tar.gz
wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8o.tar.gz

Now you have to untar these files.
tar -xvf zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz
tar -xvf pcre-8.10.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssl-0.9.8o.tar.gz
```